# Swift 3.0 Adding a Right Button to Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, button, navigationbar

I have added a navigation bar to the top of a view controller. I am trying to control whether a button is visible based a condition, but I am having trouble adding the button. So far I have,

```
var addButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "test", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let boool = true
    if boool {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addButton
    }
    else {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}

func addTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("hjxdbsdhjbv")
}
```

I believe it is not working properly because I have added a navigation bar into the VC, instead of using a navigation controller and working with the bar there. I was wondering if there was a way to work with this navigation bar.

Comment: Are you sure that `self.addButton` points to an actual `UIBarButtonItem` and is not nil?  How is it getting set?

Comment: I think you must initialize your self.addButton, before

Comment: change this line `var addButton: UIBarButtonItem!` for this one `var addButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "test", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.yourselector))`

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect the changes, but upon loading, there is still no button on the right side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say you added a `UINavigationBar` to your view controller via storyboard, but looking at the code you provided there is no outlet connection to your navigation bar in IB.

In order to access `self.navigationItem` your view controller must be embedded in a `UINavigationController` or be part of a hierarchy which is. Unless you have a need for a custom navigation bar on an individual view controller, I suggest removing that from Interface Builder, then making sure either the view controller in question is embedded in a `UINavigationController` or it is being pushed onto the navigation stack from another controller which is embedded in a navigation controller and then you should see your `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: What are the benefits for using an embedded UINavigationController over a custom navigation bar?

Comment: Having your view controllers embedded in a navigation controller allows you to have a clearly laid out navigation stack in interface builder, and for each view controller in that navigation stack, you have access to the same navigation bar. Instead you are adding one navigation bar to a view controller, and you will then have to add another one to the next view controller while managing each one separately.

Answer (score 68):

It’s simple. Put this line of code to the `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "test", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
```

***Updated for Swift 4*** or later:

A custom function:

```
@objc func action(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Function body goes here
}
```

*(Custom) Right bar button item:*

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "some_text", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.action(sender:)))
```

*(Custom) Left bar button item:*

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "some_text", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.action(sender:)))
```

Also you can add a system bar button items something like this: `UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem` Defines system-supplied images for bar button items: ***.add, .done, .cancel, .edit, .save, .compose, .reply, .organize*** and more.

(System) Right bar button item:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.add, target: self, action: #selector(self.action(sender:)))
```

(System) Left bar button item:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.add, target: self, action: #selector(self.action(sender:)))
```

Comment: Works with Swift 4

Comment: Thanks a lot but why

Answer (score 9):

```
let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: UIImage(named: "EditImage"), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.call_Method))

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem
```

Comment: @Devbot10 if you believe the question has any flaws for any reason, you have to leave a comment, not try edit someone else's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to connect you navigation bar to an IBOutlet so that you can refer to it in your code. After that, this code should work:

```
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Title")
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addButton
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    self.navigationBar.pushItem(navigationItem, animated: false)
```

Comment: I do have a back button attached with this navigation controller. I added @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar! along with your code, but by hitting the back button, it just removes the navigation bar and shows what is underneath. It is a little hard to explain, but do you know what I am saying?

Comment: The view controller it is going back to will need to have its own UINavigationBar. This is why it's better to use a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.2;

Add `viewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.addNavigationBarButton(imageName: "ic_back", direction:.left)
 }
```

Add `Class` your API or Utility Class

```
public func addNavigationBarButton(imageName:String,direction:direction){
    var image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    switch direction {
    case .left:
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style:.plain, target: nil, action: #selector(goBack))
    case .right:
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style:.plain, target: nil, action: #selector(goBack))
    }
}

@objc public func goBack() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

public enum direction {
    case right
    case left
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tested in Xcode 10.2, swift 5.0;
First, I have have embedded my ViewController in UINavigationController in IB.
Then in ViewDidLoad include these lines

```
self.title = "orange"
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(changeLayout)).
```

Note - accessing title, or adding button through navigation controller did not work. For example : setting title -  Self.navigationcontroller.navigationItem.title did not work ,