# How put UIBarButtonItem on ViewController of NavigationController on Swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem

I've a three screens for navigate. But in one these, I can't put a UIBarButtoItem. This screen, is for create a register, and I wants create a button to "Save", that simple. When I did, I select the Bar Button Item, the XCode do not leave me drop on the bar. And programatically, also not works.

I tried this: (Not happens)

```
var btSalvar : UIBarButtonItem?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btSalvar = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Salver", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btSalvar
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And in storyboard: (Note: The Button "Item" not keep fixed on the bar)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which among this is register screen?

Comment: I did edited the question with screen.

Comment: Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45069783/6680583)

Comment: @Mannopson thanks, this works.

Answer (score 1):

**You have many options to do that, One of them is:**

> You have to create a super view controller and add navigation button code in it. I have added a back button for a demo:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    /**
     To add the left back button on navigation.
     */
    var addLeftBarMenuButtonEnabled: Bool? {
        didSet {
            if addLeftBarMenuButtonEnabled! {
                let leftBarBtn = UIButton()
                leftBarBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "backIcon"), for: .normal)
                leftBarBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
                leftBarBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionBackButton), for: .touchUpInside)
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: leftBarBtn)
            } else {
                self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
    ///This is action method for back button
    @objc func actionBackButton() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

> Now you need to use the back button in your view controller which super view controller is MainViewController:

```
class ViewController: MainViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.addLeftBarMenuButtonEnabled = true
    }

}
```

**You can add navigation button like that and use where you want. If you want to use it in every view controller then you have to add 'self.addLeftBarMenuButtonEnabled = true' in main view controller like that**

```
 class MainViewController: UIViewController {


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.addLeftBarMenuButtonEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not have a solution more easy?

Comment: This is very simple solution... looking hard but it will be re-usable for your project. If you want then copy the code of button from MainViwcontroller and add this code into view controller where you to add button on the navigation

Comment: I did used this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069477/swift-3-0-adding-a-right-button-to-navigation-bar/45069783#45069783. Works perfectely